# Improve Hazelcast cluster member merge performance

Tags: merge, delay, hazelcast

I'm using a two node Hazelcast cluster using TCP/IP discovery. When one node is completely stopped, starting it up and merging works quit quickly. However, if one node loses its network/loses sight of one another, things play out quite differently. When network is back available, within seconds I see

```
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:07 | Jul 28, 2021 8:10:07 PM com.hazelcast.internal.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:07 | INFO: [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 [pmgrlab] [4.1.2] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.145.201.111:5701 and /10.145.201.110:65058
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:07 | Jul 28, 2021 8:10:07 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterJoinManager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:07 | INFO: [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 [pmgrlab] [4.1.2] We should merge to [pmgrlab1.nxodev.intra]:5701, both have the same data member count: 1
```

So, almost immediately the cluster node sees it should join again. But instead of joining, there's a lengthy wait, followed by another two

```
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:52 | Jul 28, 2021 8:10:52 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterJoinManager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:52 | INFO: [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 [pmgrlab] [4.1.2] We should merge to [pmgrlab1.nxodev.intra]:5701, both have the same data member count: 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:57 | Jul 28, 2021 8:10:57 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterJoinManager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:57 | INFO: [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 [pmgrlab] [4.1.2] We should merge to [pmgrlab1.nxodev.intra]:5701, both have the same data member count: 1
```

and finally, the merge is then starting

```
> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2021/07/28 20:10:57 | WARNING: [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 [pmgrlab] [4.1.2] [pmgrlab2.nxodev.intra]:5701 is merging [tcp/ip] to [pmgrlab1.nxodev.intra]:5701
```

Now there's 50 seconds in between the nodes seeing each other again, and actually starting the merge.

I've already tried setting `hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds` and `hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds` to lower values (tried 15 for now), but the scenario above is with 15 seconds, and still we have a 50 seconds delay until the merge.

I'm guessing there's some safety margins to prevent flapping, but 50 seconds seems excessive. Any ideas as to what parameters I need to change to make this work out quicker?

Comment: Have you resolved it? It looks like I have a similar problem. Please describe your case and your solution, if yes.

Comment: What was the resolution for this? I am running into similar issue where merge is taking too long!

Comment: I'm afraid I never found a solution. Or rather, the solution was to chuck Hazelcast and write my own thing (I only needed a small part of Hazelcast)